# Declarar variable en procedimiento almacenado MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda de cómo realizar el siguiente procedimiento:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure insertaEmpleado (nombre varchar(50), apPat varchar(50), apMat varchar(50), apodo varchar(50), calle varchar(50), colonia varchar(50), numero varchar(5), municipio varchar(50), email varchar(50), sexo char(1), fechaNac date, telefono varchar(15), usuario varchar(50), pass varchar(50))
BEGIN
insert into persona values (null, nombre, apPat, apMat, apodo, calle, colonia, numero, municipio, email, sexo, fechaNac, telefono);
declare idPer;
set idPer = select max(idPer) from empleado;
insert into empleado values (null, usuario, pass, idPer);
END
$$
```

Lo que deseo es ingresar valores en dos tablas. Pero para ingresar en la segunda tabla necesito el [ultimo id que se ingresó, pero me marca error. No estoy tan bien en MySQL. ¿Alguien que me oriente en la sintaxis correcta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeramente, para declarar una variable como `idPer`, el nombre debe comenzar con el símbolo `@`: `@idPer`.

Segundo, como se trata de una variable a la que quieres asignarle el resultado de una consulta, eso lo puedes hacer directamente en la consulta haciendo la asignación con el operador `:=`:

```
select @idPer := max(idPer) from empleado;
```

De modo que el procedimiento almacenado siguiente debería funcionar correctamente:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure insertaEmpleado (nombre varchar(50), apPat varchar(50), apMat varchar(50), apodo varchar(50), calle varchar(50), colonia varchar(50), numero varchar(5), municipio varchar(50), email varchar(50), sexo char(1), fechaNac date, telefono varchar(15), usuario varchar(50), pass varchar(50))
BEGIN
insert into persona values (null, nombre, apPat, apMat, apodo, calle, colonia, numero, municipio, email, sexo, fechaNac, telefono);
select @idPer := max(idPer) from empleado;
insert into empleado values (null, usuario, pass, @idPer);
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Referencia útil: [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

---

Sin embargo, aunque funcione, esta forma de hacerlo no es eficiente. A medida que crezca la tabla `empleado`, la consulta que busca el `max(idPer)` va a ir llendo más y más lento.

Como parece que estás usando campos `AUTO_INCREMENT` para tus claves primarias, lo más eficiente es que uses la función [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) para devolver el último `idPer` insertado:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure insertaEmpleado (nombre varchar(50), apPat varchar(50), apMat varchar(50), apodo varchar(50), calle varchar(50), colonia varchar(50), numero varchar(5), municipio varchar(50), email varchar(50), sexo char(1), fechaNac date, telefono varchar(15), usuario varchar(50), pass varchar(50))
BEGIN
insert into persona values (null, nombre, apPat, apMat, apodo, calle, colonia, numero, municipio, email, sexo, fechaNac, telefono);
insert into empleado values (null, usuario, pass, LAST_INSERT_ID());
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Como comentario final, te recomiendo de siempre nombrar las columnas explícitamente en tus sentencias `INSERT`. Esto te protegerá de cualquier cambio en la estructura de las tablas, como nuevas columnas, etc.

Comment: He intentado lo mismo pero me ha marcado error, lo que he hecho mejor es realizar las operaciones por separadas por mientras, en estos días indagaré bien el asunto gracias!

Comment: Podrías agregar la forma alternativa `select max(idPer) from empleado into @idPer;`